# Et puis, il tressaillait, comme si un courant électrique l'avait traversé

Tags: imparfait

*Les embrouilles de Calma* de Barry Jonsberg :

Calma et Kiffo se trouvent dans un hôpital suite à un accident. Calma essaie d'expliquer à son ami qu'il s'agit d'une malchance et non d'une attaque.

> Kiffo continuait cependant à rouler des yeux. Je n'en voyais plus que
> le blanc. Et puis, il **tressaillait**, comme si un courant électrique
> l'avait traversé.

Est-ce que l'auteur emploie l'imparfait ici pour faire une description et Kiffo a tressaillé une seule fois ou Kiffo a tressaillé plusieurs fois de suite ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas l'auteur. C'est le traducteur: [Luc Rigoureau](https://twilightsaga.fandom.com/fr/wiki/Luc_Rigoureau)

Comment: Continuait, tressaillait : cela semble être lié et une action qui dure.

Comment: @Ptit Xav a raison: Ici, l'imparfait indique une action qui dure. L'original en anglais (de Google books) *But Kiffo was still rolling his eyes. I could see nothing but the whites. And he was twitching, like an electric current was going through him.*

Comment: @PeterShor It must be easy for you to see that from a library book. Where I live, I can't get to the books online. Finally, we see the English. Thanks for posting that.

Answer (score 4):

En lisant le texte français, je comprends qu'il tressaillait encore après que le courant électrique avait fini de le traverser.

En lisant le texte anglais, je comprends que le courant électrique continuait de le traverser pendant qu'il tressaillait.

À mon humble avis, s'il y a confusion c'est plutôt dans le temps du verbe traverser que dans celui de tressaillir:

> Kiffo continuait cependant à rouler des yeux. Je n'en voyais plus que le blanc. Et puis, il tressaillait, comme si un courant électrique le **traversait**.

Comment: Oui. Mais dans cette nouvelle version, s'agit-il de la description d'une action (traverser, tressaillir) ou d'une série (traverser et tresaillit plusieurs fois) ?

Comment: À mon avis ce n'est pas une série. Je ne pense pas qu'on puisse transcrire une série juste avec un choix  de temps de verbe. On utilise plutôt des qualificatifs: *il tressaillait par saccades* par exemple.

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce cas, comme Ptit Xav dit dans un commentaire, l'imparfait sert à indiquer que l'action dure plus que quelques instants. L'original, en anglais, est

> But Kiffo was still rolling his eyes. I could see nothing but the whites. And he was twitching, like an electric current was going through him.

Et en anglais, c'est le passé continu qui indique la même chose.

Comment: Merci ! Ok, grâce à l'original en anglais, on comprend mieux, mais il serait aussi possible, sans l'original, de supposer l'imparfait pittoresque, qui a la même même valeur que le passé simple. [imparfait pittoresque (9)](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/121371/SpisyFF_212-1978-1_3.pdf?sequence=1)